# Start docker container with PostgreSQL as a fixture in conjunction with pytest-postgresql plugin

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, pytest, psycopg3

Recently I began to use pytest-postgresql plugin to test my app. I start docker container manually using `docker run ...` command, then I run my tests and it works like a charm.
My `conftest.py` looks like this:

```py
from pytest_postgresql import factories


postgresql_noproc = factories.postgresql_noproc(
    host="127.0.0.1",
    port=65432,
    password="supersecretpassword",
)
postgres_client = factories.postgresql("postgresql_noproc")
```

and here is a simple test:

```py
from psycopg import sql
from psycopg.rows import dict_row


def test_tables_count(postgres_client):
    with postgres_client.cursor(row_factory=dict_row) as cursor:
        cursor.execute(
            sql.SQL(
                "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables "
                "WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'"
                " AND table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')"
            )
        )
        result = cursor.fetchone()
    assert result["count"] == 0
```

Now I want to start container automatically using [docker-py](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library before initializing pytest-postgresql fixtures.

I added a fixture that would run a container:

```py
import time

import docker
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def psql_docker():
    client = docker.from_env()
    container = client.containers.run(
        image="postgres:12",
        auto_remove=True,
        environment=dict(
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD="supersecretpassword",
        ),
        name="test_postgres",
        ports={"5432/tcp": ("127.0.0.1", 65432)},
        detach=True,
        remove=True,
    )
    
    # Wait for the container to start
    # (actually I use more complex check to wait for container to start but it doesn't really matter)
    time.sleep(5)
    
    yield

    container.stop()
```

How can I make this fixture run before other factories? I understand that `factories.postgresql_noproc` and `factories.postgresql` fixture factories are module level entities and they initialize before `psql_docker` runs.

### What I tried

##### Attempt #0

I tried to convert `postgres_client` to a custom fixture:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def postgres_client(psql_docker):
    return factories.postgresql("postgresql_noproc")
```

but the test failed:

```
postgres_client = <function postgresql.<locals>.postgresql_factory at 0x7f810cb0d670>

    def test_tables_count(postgres_client):
>       with postgres_client.cursor(row_factory=dict_row) as cursor:
E       AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'cursor'

tests/unit_postgres_so/test_psql_connection.py:6: AttributeError
=========================================================================================================================== short test summary info ============================================================================================================================
FAILED tests/unit_postgres_so/test_psql_connection.py::test_tables_count - AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```

I guess this happens because `postgres_client` now returns a function object, not a fixture result.

##### Attempt #1

Almost the same, but in `postgres_client` fixture I return a function result:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def postgres_client(psql_docker):
    return factories.postgresql("postgresql_noproc")()
```

Again, the test fails. This time with an error that says: "Fixture "postgresql_factory" called directly". I followed the [link](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/deprecations.html#calling-fixtures-directly) from that message, but I can't understand how it may help.

Of course, I can get rid of pytest-postgresql plugin and write my own fixture that'll be able to connect to dockerized PostgreSQL instance, but I really don't want to do it. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So under the hood `pytest_postgresql` creates an instance of a [DatabaseJanitor](https://github.com/ClearcodeHQ/pytest-postgresql/blob/main/src/pytest_postgresql/factories/noprocess.py#L86) for the `noproc` method. We can simply recreate this methodology and create our own fixture where we inject our dependency on `docker` in to it.

```
# conftest.py
import time

import docker
import psycopg
import pytest
from pytest_postgresql.janitor import DatabaseJanitor

POSTGRES_PASSWORD = "supersecretpassword"
PORT = 65432
USER = "postgres"
DB = "postgres"


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def psql_docker():
    client = docker.from_env()
    container = client.containers.run(
        image="postgres:12",
        auto_remove=True,
        environment=dict(
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD=POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
        ),
        name="test_postgres",
        ports={"5432/tcp": ("127.0.0.1", PORT)},
        detach=True,
        remove=True,
    )

    # Wait for the container to start
    # (actually I use more complex check to wait for container to start but it doesn't really matter)
    time.sleep(5)

    yield

    container.stop()


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def database(psql_docker):
    with DatabaseJanitor(
        user=USER,
        host="localhost",
        port=PORT,
        dbname=f"{DB}_tmpl",
        version=12,
        password=POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
    ):
        yield psycopg.connect(
            dbname=DB,
            user=USER,
            password=POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
            host="localhost",
            port=PORT,
        )

# test_file.py
from psycopg import sql
from psycopg.rows import dict_row


def test_tables_count(database):
    with database.cursor(row_factory=dict_row) as cursor:
        cursor.execute(
            sql.SQL(
                "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables "
                "WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'"
                " AND table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')"
            )
        )
        result = cursor.fetchone()
    assert result["count"] == 0
```

Now it works as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It works, though there was a minor problem I came up. Before running any tests I need to execute a SQL script that creates tables with some test data in them. I added `janitor.load("tests/unit_postgres_so/sql/tables.sql")` in `database` fixture before yielding psycopg connection, but janitor executes this commands in `postgres_tmpl` database, not in `postgres`. I fixed database name in psycopg.connect() parameters and now it finally works as expected but I have no idea why DatabaseJanitor really needs this _tmpl suffix.

Comment: By the way I can't use `postgres` as a database name in both DatabaseJanitor and psycopg.connect(), because in that case janitor says that `postgres` database already exists. So `database_tmpl` or whatever suffix it'll be is the only way for all that stuff to work. Janitor has to create its own database, hasn't it?

Comment: yes that is correct, it is a feature of the class -> https://github.com/ClearcodeHQ/pytest-postgresql/blob/main/src/pytest_postgresql/janitor.py#L61 . you also could remove the call to connect and just use the `cursor` from the `janitor` --> https://github.com/ClearcodeHQ/pytest-postgresql/blob/main/src/pytest_postgresql/janitor.py#L134 . you also could override the `init` method in a custom class, lots of options

Comment: thanks again! I think this solution is the one I was looking for